# How to run svn when ssh over ssh?

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting, ssh-tunneling

I need to run `sudo -u wwwrun sh -c 'svn status -uq /srv/www/htdocs/loquat'` over ssh. When using one ssh it works smoothly. Now there is one server that needs to be connected through another server via ssh.

If I issue

```
sudo ssh -t root@pacific ssh root@loquat "sudo -u wwwrun sh -c 'svn status -uq /srv/www/htdocs/loquat'" 2>&1
```

I get `Type 'svn help' for usage.`

But when I do `sudo ssh -t root@pacific ssh root@loquat` I am connected to the desired server and then running `sudo -u wwwrun sh -c 'svn status -uq /srv/www/htdocs/loquat` manually gives me correct output.

And when I run `sudo ssh -t root@pacific ssh root@loquat "sudo -u wwwrun sh -c 'id'" 2>&1` I get correctly `uid=30(wwwrun) gid=8(www) groups=8(www),1001(eduserver)`

What do I need to do to fix that?

- OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8j-fips 07 Jan 2009
- SuSE 10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo ssh root@pacific ssh root@loquat sudo -u wwwrun svn status -uq /srv/www/htdocs/loquat 2>&1
```

Comment: Works, could you explain?

Comment: The bash removes quotes when interpreting a command. So when you 'nesting' commands over a long chain of sudo's ssh's and sh's the final command looks not as you expect. Also I removed unnecessary 'sh -c' as it only complicates the things in your case. also I had to add -- 'switch' to sudo to make it stopping to scan the command for switches and treat the rest as a whole command to execute

Comment: One more question. Maybe related....If I run above command from a command line as php use it's ok. If I run from the browser it's ok but the first line is "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal." Any idea?

Comment: Do you need pty to be allocated? I suppose - no, taking to account that you run it from php script on a web server. Just remove -t switch